# Substituting excel cell with a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel column A which contains some data. If the cell starts with `</li>` then the every `</li>` should be replaced by `<u>`. The formula should not replace `</li>` appearing any where except the first one.

Comment: I can do simple substitution but I cannot do this kind of substituion with a condition. I completely don't know about this.

Comment: Which way do you do the "simple substitution"? Take note that your question is imprecise. You say, "then every `</li>` should be replaced". You also say "The formula should not replace `</li>` ... except the first one". May we presume from your use of the word "formula" that you are looking for a formula?

Comment: If I got your question right, this should do the trick for you: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "^\<\/li\>", "<u>")`

Comment: @IvankaTodorova - REGEXREPLACE is not a function in Excel VBA - but it is in a Google Spreadsheet

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I thought that there was something *fishy*... That's why I posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula, (obv sub A1 with the cell where the text to replace are):

```
=IF(LEFT(A1;5)="</li>";SUBSTITUTE(A1;"</li>";"<u>");A1)
```

[image: Here's a sample]

But if you want to replace only the first  instance in the cell who start with , you should do:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1;5)="</li>";SUBSTITUTE(A1;"</li>";"<u>";1);A1)
```

We use the "instance_num" parameter of the substitute function, to tell her to replace only the first instance, here what happens:

[image: Second sample]